# MongoDB: aggregation, $group by multiple (two) fields, with sorting (receiving latest) results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am dealing with a pretty strange case, of aggregation in Mongo. I have a pretty standard collection, with the following schema/fields:

```
{
  price: Number,
  conneected_realm_id: Number, /** <= destination or warehouse pointer */
  item.id: Number, /** Some kind of SKU */
  last_modified: Number /** Unix timestamp, the latest documents has greater results, always */
}
```

And my aggregation query, which I was always sure, returning me a `-latest results`, but as I understood now, it actually didn't.

#### THE PROBLEM:

[MongoPlayground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v0upvK1eqDB)

The collection receives a real-time data, and store it. Every `item` with his own `connected_realm_id` field (this warehouse/pointed data) has it's own unique timestamps. So it's like:

```
  item: 168652
  in warehouses: 1602 | 1063
  timestamps:  -latest for each
                  7       5
                  4       3 /** <= this are outdated timestamps */
                  2       1 /** <= and so is this */
```

So, by my aggregation in MongoPlayground, I want to receiving the following data

```
All original documents with:
 item: 168652
 groupedBy: { 1602 and 7 }, { 1603 and 5 } /** latest ($max) timestamps for each warehouse */
```

instead, I receive each unique timestamp for each warehouse, but I don't need it. So, the question is: can the following data be achieved?

A bit more info:

- Mongo v4.2, so I could use almost every operator, except `$replaceOne`
- I know, I could solve this problem, with  making N (warehouse count) requests, or via `.eachAsync`, but it's not a solution, because I have 200+ warehouses. I am capable to add one more stage at my query (which quite long enough, trust me), but I am not capable of making N request to DB with `{$match: { connected_realm_id: value, last_modified: -latest } }`
- collection already has indexes, one of them is `compound` by `connected_realm_id && last_modified`, so if I use `$match` or `.find()` I receive a pre-sorted values from a DB.
- ***Just to be clear, this whole things is about saving/filtering default `$$ROOT` documents. So I don't need to receive the latest timestamp for each *warehouse*. I can receive this data via another and more efficient way, the whole point is in filtering/saving the `{data: $$ROOT}` field***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to receiving the following data

```
 item: 168652
 groupedBy: { 1602 and 7 }, { 1603 and 5 }
```

1. You need to group at item at the last
2. Initially you need to group at realm, then you need to get latest timestamp i.e max

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jMmjtqmMQfo)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        connected_realm_id: "$connected_realm_id"
      },
      "data": {
        "$max": "$last_modified"
      },
      "item": {
        "$first": "$item.id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "connected_realm_id": "$_id.connected_realm_id",
      "last_modified": "$data",
      "item": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$item",
      "groupedBy": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**EDIT:**

[this one?](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oSdiRAABcEb)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        connected_realm_id: "$connected_realm_id",
        latest_timestamp: {
          $max: "$last_modified"
        },
        
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        connected_realm_id: "$data.connected_realm_id"
      },
      "data": {
        "$max": "$data.last_modified"
      },
      "item": {
        "$first": "$data.item.id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "connected_realm_id": "$_id.connected_realm_id",
      "last_modified": "$data",
      "item": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$item",
      "groupedBy": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Update:**

As OP derived from above edit, [this solves OP's problem](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vAV9iOpY0Xk)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        connected_realm_id: "$connected_realm_id",
        latest_timestamp: {
          $max: "$last_modified"
        },
        
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        connected_realm_id: "$data.connected_realm_id"
      },
      "data": {
        "$max": "$data.last_modified"
      },
      "item": {
        "$push": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: I am checking it, this whole things is about saving/filtering default `$$ROOT` documents. So just to be clear, I don't need to receive the latest timestamp for each *warehouse*. I need to `filter` data.

Comment: What do you mean by that? The time you run the query, you will not have timestamp?

Comment: Just take a look at my example at [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/v0upvK1eqDB) the main point is filtering the docs, like in `{data: $$ROOT}` field, not receiving a distinct value of latest timestamp of each warehouse.

Comment: [kind of this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oSdiRAABcEb) ? I am still not understanding

Comment: No. Look at this [data set example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X4Vg0_9juOK). Documents in the left column, represent the data that I need to receive. For each `connected_realm_id` with it's own maximum `timestamp` field, with documents in `data` field. Another words: **$$ROOT documents**, `filtereredBy/groupedBy: connected_realm_id and max(last_modified)`

Comment: thank you, I think this [snippet](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vAV9iOpY0Xk) of yours, is very helpfull, just needed to add one more stage.

Answer (score 0):

The correct (final solution) at [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9EcZjUFwYsh)

Dataset:

```
[
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 1596719280
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 1596719280
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 1596719280
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 1596719280
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 2
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 3
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 4
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 5
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 1596719280
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1602,
    last_modified: 1596719280
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 1596719267
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 1596719267
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 1596719267
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 1596719267
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 1
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 2
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 3
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 4
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 5
  },
  {
    item: {
      id: 168652
    },
    connected_realm_id: 1603,
    last_modified: 1596719267
  }
]
```

Aggregation Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        connected_realm_id: "$connected_realm_id"
      },
      latest: {
        $max: "$last_modified"
      },
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "data.latest": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$data.last_modified",
              "$latest"
            ]
          },
          then: "$latest",
          else: "$false"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "latest": {
        "$exists": true,
        "$ne": null
      }
    }
  }
])
```